# Rspec: testing model class method

Tags: ruby, class, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I am trying to test the model class method. here's how model looks like

```
class Abc
  class Dbc < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = 'vSomeView'

    def self.class_method(user_id)
      Dbc
      .select('vSomeView.column')
      .where("vSomeView.UserID = #{user_id}")
      .first
    end
  end
end
```

factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :dbc, class: Abc::Dbc do
  column { 'value' }
  ...
  end
end
```

Rspec

```
RSpec.describe Abc::Dbc, type: :model do
  let(:user) { create(:user) }
  let(:dbc) { build_stubbed(:dbc, user: user) }

  describe '.class_method' do
    it 'returns column value' do
      response = dbc.class_method(user.user_id)
      expect(response.column). to eq('value')
    end
  end
end
```

But i am getting error class_method when i run rspec. What is it i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

When you use factory girl to `build` an instance, it will build you an instance instantiated from that `class`.

What you want is

```
Abc::Dbc.class_method(...)
```